# Optimization of foreach for thousands items

Tags: php, memory, optimization, yii, foreach

I'm running the code below over a set of **25,000** results. I need to **optimize** it because i'm hitting the memory limit.

```
$oldproducts = Oldproduct::model()->findAll(); /*(here i have 25,000 results)*/

foreach($oldproducts as $oldproduct) :
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('`someid`', $oldproduct->someid);
    $finds = Newproduct::model()->findAll($criteria);

    if (empty($finds)) {
        $new = new Newproduct;
        $new->someid = $oldproduct->someid;
        $new->save();
    } else {
        foreach($finds as $find) :
            if ($find->price != $oldproduct->price) {
                $find->attributes=array('price' => $oldproduct->price);
                $find->save();
            }
        endforeach;
    }
endforeach;
```

Code compares rows of two tables by *someid*. If it find coincidence it updates *price* column, if not creates a new record.

Comment: What line are you hitting the error on? Why can't you just do this with an SQL query? It will take some time, but go through batches of 100 at a time instead of fetching all 25K. (an outer loop being `for ($offset = 0; $offset < 25000; $offset += 100)`).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) as long as the code works and the question fits their guidelines.

Comment: You are using ActiveRecords for a huge amount of data, which is a definitly a NO NO. Try to avoid ActiveRecords in these kind of situations.

Comment: I can't use SQL because, this code must check if there is a new records in Oldproduct table by button click. It will be used often

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`CDataProviderIterator`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProviderIterator) which:

> ... allows iteration over large data sets without holding the entire set in memory.

You first have to pass a `CDataProvider` instance to it:

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider("Oldproduct");
$iterator = new CDataProviderIterator($dataProvider);
foreach($iterator as $item) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could process the rows in chunks of ~5000 instead of getting all the rows in 1 go!

```
$cnt = 5000;
$offset = 0;

do {
    $oldproducts = Oldproduct::model()->limit($cnt)->offset($offset)->findAll(); /*(here i have 25,000 results)*/

    foreach($oldproducts as $oldproduct) {
        // your code
    }

    $offset += $cnt;
} while($oldproducts >= $cnt);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but there is an error - " do not have a method or closure named "limit"."