# Yii CActiveDataProvider items count different

Tags: php, yii

i am new to Yii. and i have the followin code in Yii.

```
public function actionExport($typeid=0, $locationid=0, $sidx='date_input', $sord='desc',  

$kategori='', $to = 'xls'){
    // inisialisasi criteria query
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->order = "$sidx $sord";

    // filter lokasi
    if (is_numeric($locationid) && $locationid !== 0)
    {
        $criteria->with = array('data'=>array(
            'condition'=>'data.locationid=:locationid',
            'params'=>array(':locationid'=>$locationid)
        ));
    } else {
        if (is_numeric($typeid) && $typeid !== 0)
        {
            $criteria->with = array('data.location'=>array(
                'with'=>array(
                    'type'=>array(
                        'condition'=>'type.typeid=:typeid',
                        'params'=>array(':typeid'=>$typeid)
                    )
                )
            ));
        } else {
            $criteria->with = array('data.location'=>array(
                'with'=>array(
                    'type'=>array(
                        'condition'=>'type.type_desc=:type_desc',
                        'params'=>array(':type_desc'=>$kategori)
                    )
                )
            ));
        }
    }

    // filter range tanggal
    if (isset($_REQUEST['startdate'], $_REQUEST['enddate']))
    {
        $startdate = $_REQUEST['startdate'];
        $enddate = $_REQUEST['enddate'];
        $criteria->condition = 'date_input <= :enddate AND date_input >= :startdate';
        $criteria->params = array(':startdate'=>$startdate, ':enddate'=>$enddate);
    }

    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('InputData', array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria
    ));

    echo $dataProvider->getTotalItemCount(); // this is about 5623

    if($to == 'xls'){
        $this->_toXls($dataProvider->getData());
    }else{

    }
}
```

this line `echo $dataProvider->getTotalItemCount()` print 5623, but in loop `this->_toXls()` the row get printed in excel file is only 10 row. same result when i am debugging the dataprovider using `print_r($dataProvider->getData())`, it's 10 items.

am i wrong in writing the code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable pagination:

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('InputData', array(
    'criteria' => $criteria
    'pagination' => false
));
```

As an addition you may need to iterate through your items in batches to save on memory as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24289493/428543)

Answer (score 0):

You should check out if $dataProvider is paginated:

```
 $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('InputData', array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
    'pagination' => array(
        'pageSize' => 25,
    ),
));
```

Try this and find out if the rows are 25.

To remove pagination you can simply set pagination to false.

```
 $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('InputData', array(
   'criteria'=>$criteria,
   'pagination' => false,
  ),
));
```

Link: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProvider#pagination-detail

Comment: The proper way is to set pagination to false.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you are not wrong. It is just DataProvider pagination. You can turn it off like this

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('InputData', array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
    'pagination' => FALSE,
));
```