# Yii findAll() causes memory issue

Tags: php, memory, mysqli, yii, yii2

The no of records i have is just 15000. and the memory php is configured to use is 128 mb. so i get this error.

Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

there are 2 ways to handle this.

1. DAO http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao
2. Increasing the memory allowed in PHP

What i am confused at is,  if i increase the memory allowed to 256, one day when the number of data becomes 30 000 this error will come again.

so should i not use Yii cactiverecord findAll() when i am developing large scale applications ? or i should keep increasing the memory size as more data comes in.

what is the best approach ?

Comment: Use `createCommand` with custom queries i.e; fetch only what you need and use indexes.

Comment: It's not really a solution to verry large model arrays but what you can do is user ->select() to only select the data you need so if you want to display a name you dont need the id, email excetra. than you can do is Customer::find()->select('name')->all()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optimization of foreach for thousands items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284551/optimization-of-foreach-for-thousands-items)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to retrive data with batches:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#data-in-batches

```
// fetch 10 customers at a time
foreach (Customer::find()->batch(10) as $customers) {
    // $customers is an array of 10 or fewer Customer objects
}

// fetch 10 customers at a time and iterate them one by one
foreach (Customer::find()->each(10) as $customer) {
    // $customer is a Customer object
}

// batch query with eager loading
foreach (Customer::find()->with('orders')->each() as $customer) {
    // $customer is a Customer object with the 'orders' relation populated
}
```

Comment: Hah. And I've used a ported version of CDataProviderIterator to do this. Silly me.

Comment: @dev1234 it depends. Each batch is a new sql query so it should take longer. You can adjust the batch size for optimum speed and memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue, after days research the problem is object of activeRecord are pacth in to memory with all object of its relation, that make increasing occupy memory, so my solution is make function that unset that relation object and that object itself each time looping, add this code bellow inside that object class model like this:

```
class ModelObject{
   ....

   public function unsetModel()
   {
       foreach($this->getRelatedRecords() as $name => $record)
       {
           unset($this->{$name});
       }
       unset($this);
   }

   ....
}
```

and call that function inside foreach like this:

```
foreach($modelObjects as $model)
{
     ....

     $model->unsetModel();
}
```