# Is there query limitation on Yii 1 framework?

Tags: php, yii

I am doing project in Yii 1. And I am facing this problem.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->condition = 'status > 4';
$criteria->limit = 5000;
$models = Data::model()->findAll($criteria);     
print_r(count($models));
```

Than its working fine but when I run the query without criteria or criteria with higher than 7000 limitation i.e.

```
$models = Data::model()->findAll();
```

or

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->condition = 'status > 4';
$criteria->limit = 7000;
$models = Data::model()->findAll($criteria);     
print_r(count($models));
```

its not retrieving any data. Any help??

Comment: Have you enabled error reporting?

Comment: Yeah I have just enabled error_reporting(E_ALL); still its not retrieving any data..  :(

Comment: You are running apache right?  Check your apache error.log and php_error_log.  Likely to be memory issue

Comment: Yeah..  LAMP stack from  digitalocean

Comment: Is there any reason you're fetching 7000 items at once? Why even show the user 7000 items? Why not use a loading scroller using ajax that only fetches 20 items at a time similarly to paging?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284551/optimization-of-foreach-for-thousands-items/24289493#24289493

Comment: Guys.. I am just trying to update bulk data from backend..  Not retrieving data to show the users..

Comment: check logs. protected/runtime/application.log is the default one if you haven't configured anything. you can also tell yii to log only sql queries, so check what query it is trying to execute.

Comment: Consider this might be a memory issue as activerecords have a lot of overhead. You could try simple SQL or pagination (even for processing) as suggested in previous comments