# Download CSV files using PHP with 100K+ Records

Tags: php, csv, yii

I have written a code to download csv file and it works perfectly, But if the number of records (rows) are more than 100,000+ it gives an error..

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)
```

It is because I am fetching the entire result into an array and then loop over it with foreach().

```
$query = "SELECT msisdn, duration FROM `users` WHERE id=".$id.";"; 
$dataProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($query);
$results = $dataProvider->getData();

    // opening file
    $fp = fopen($filename, "w");

    fwrite($fp, "Msisdn,,Duration (seconds) \r\n");

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        fwrite($fp, $result['msisdn'] . ",," . $result['duration'] . "\r\n");
    }
    // closing file;
    fclose($fp);
    exit;
```

and i think it is much more memory efficient to use a while() loop to fetch and process one row at a time. How do i do this with in php yii 1.1 framework??

something like this..

```
while($row = $nextrow)
   fwrite();
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Yep, more efficient, but more DB load. Try limit+offset, and just add new rows.

Comment: $query = "SELECT msisdn, duration FROM `users` WHERE id=".$id." limit 50000 offset 0;"; - first query. 
$query = "SELECT msisdn, duration FROM `users` WHERE id=".$id." limit 50000 offset 50000"; - second query

Comment: And when result of query is empty - stop the script.

Comment: How will query run twice? i mean both queries

Comment: In for/while loop :)

Comment: Yii has a data provider iterator. Unfortunately it is only suited for CActive DataProvider. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24289493/428543)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Yii, you should [CDbDataReader](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbDataReader). It represents a forward-only stream of rows from a query result set.

Pass your sql query to this command.

```
$command= Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query);
$dataReader=$command->query();
```

Then loop the dataReader. Your code will be

```
foreach($dataReader as $result){
    fwrite($fp, $result['msisdn'] . ",," . $result['duration'] . "\r\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks you +1, It helped me with downloading 1 million records without any problems

Answer (score 2):

You get the total records from that table and split it based on the count. So then next you while loop the above result and the queries.